# Solve very large Hilbert matrix programmatically

Tags: python, numpy, algebra

There's a problem I'm working on for school where I need to solve a very large system of equations (1million x 1million matrix) where the solution is a 1 million vector of all ones.

```
A = [  1    1/2    1/3    1/4   ...   1/n
     1/2    1/3    1/4    1/5   ...   1/n+1
     1/3    1/4    1/5    1/6   ...   1/n+2
      .      .      .      .     .     .
      .      .      .      .     .     .
     1/n    1/n+1  1/n+2  1/n+3 ...   1/2n-1 ]

 b = [1,1,1,...,1]^T  (lenght = n)

 n = 1x10^6

 Ax = b  <-- solve this system of equations
```

I've been able to solve this using Python and the Numpy module with n = 1x10^5 in about 16 minutes. However, when I try to solve for n = 1x10^6 it takes a very (very!) long time, 18 hours and counting, ram at 100%.

Is there an algorithm to solve this system of equations more efficiently? I believe numpy.linalg.solve() uses Gaussian elimination.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried inverting A and multiplying it by b?

Comment: Yeah, it works very well when n = 10k but when I go up to 100k or 1M it still takes a very long time

Comment: Did you invert A or do b/A?

Comment: I tried inverting A

Comment: try b/A it should give the same answer. Inverting takes a long time.

Comment: So divide a vector by a matrix?

Comment: OK just tried this and the results don't satisfy the equations